# binary numbers in gawk

Tags: gawk, radix

How can one specify a number as binary in `gawk`?

According to the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal_002dnumbers.html), `gawk` interprets all numbers as decimal unless they are preceded by a `0` (octal) or by a `0x` (hexadecimal). Unlike in certain other languages, `0b` does not do the trick.

For instance, the following lines do not give the desired output (`010000` or `10000`) because the values are interpreted as octal/decimal or decimal/decimal, respectively:

```
gawk '{print and(010000,110000)}'
0

gawk '{print and(10000,110000)}'
9488
```

I suspect that `gawk` may not support base-2 and that a user-defined function will be required to generate binary representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, there's no internal support for binary conversion in gawk.  And incredibly, there isn't even any in `printf()`.  So you're stuck with functions.

Remember that awk is [*weakly typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing).  Which is why functions have insane behaviours like recognizing that "0x" at the beginning of a string means it's a hexadecimal number.  In a language like this, better to control your own types.

Here's a couple of functions I've had sitting around for years...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f

function bin2dec(n) {
  result = 0;
  if (n~/[^01]/) {
    return n;
  }
  for (i=length(n); i; i--) {
    result += 2^(length(n)-i) * substr(n,i,1);
  }
  return result;
}

function dec2bin(n) {
  result = "";
  while (n) {
    if (n%2) {
      result = "1" result;
    } else {
      result = "0" result;
    }
    n = int(n/2);
  }
  return result;
}

{
  print dec2bin( and(bin2dec($1),bin2dec($2)) );
}
```

And the result:

```
$ echo "1101 1011" | ./doit.awk
1001
$ echo "11110 10011" | ./doit.awk
10010
$
```